# How to determine what kind of error is returned from $http request in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I've been working with angular and I have an error when I do a ajax request post with angularjs I don`t know what is the error just  I can see a message, I would like to know what kind error is it more details.

```
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log("error");
    });
```

Comment: If you want to know what the body of the response is, print the data. If you want to know what the status is, print the status. If you want to know what the headers are, print the headers. There is no other available information: angular can't know anything other than what the server sends in the response.

Comment: Why an ajax request can be canceled at AngularJS?